# Python: submodule not seen, even though `__init__.py` is present?

Tags: python

Assuming `root` represents a directory - the root of the project.
There is `root/__init__.py` in order to notify Python that `root` itself is a package. Then there is submodule: `root/submodule_a` and appropriate `root/submodule_a/__init__.py`; same story with `root/submodule_b/__init__.py`. In other words: I got two submodels of the same depth.

The problem is that `submodule_a` is seen by the Python, while `submodule_b` is not. I run `import root` and then `dir(root)`; it comes up with following response:

```
['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'submodule_a']
```

...`submodule_b` (which is defined in exactly the same fashion at exactly the same level) is not seen.

Why?

Comment: Please add some information to your question: are you saying you have an empty `__init__.py` in all three folders (`root`, `root/submodule_a` and `root/submodule_b`)? And there is nothing else in these folders? You are running the import from a Python interpreter that has the parent folder of root as a working directory?

Comment: @Grismar, nope, none is empty. There is code doing something related to that module, nothing else. The only empty one is `root/__init__.py`. Python interpreter is fine.

Comment: If they are not empty, then you should share their contents here - it is impossible to tell you what is wrong without knowing the situation. I would recommend removing everything that has nothing to do with the problem and provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You have to `import root.sub` to access those, it's not automatic. You *could* put `from . import sub` in `__init__.py` though, but that's sometimes considered bad practice.